# How to write a Haar measure on $SO(n)$ and $SU(n)$ given Haar measure on $GL(n)$?

Tags: haar-measure

> How to write a Haar measure on $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ and $\operatorname{SU}(n)$ given Haar measure on $\operatorname{GL}(n)\,$?

I know that $\operatorname{GL}(n)$ has the Haar measure $(\det(A)^{-1} dA)$.

I try to write from these a Haar measure for the compact groups $\operatorname{SO}(n)$ and $\operatorname{SU}(n)$.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1364495/haar-measure-on-son) might be helpful.

Comment: something withouth spheric coordinates?

Comment: If you want a density for the Haar measure, you will have to use some coordinates.

Comment: using classical coordinates?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Note that $SO(n)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and not an open set like $GL(n)$. In particular, $SO(n)$ has Lebesgue measure zero (as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$) and therefore the Haar measure on $SO(n)$ cannot have a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.

Comment: I believe there is a typo in your formula for the Haar measure on the general linear group; see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3815324/169085.

Comment: Further, a method of getting the density for the Haar measure on the special linear group would be through the Iwasawa decomposition. See Howe & Tan's book "Non-Abelian Harmonic Analysis", p.206, Prop.1.1.11 for the $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ case and Wallach's book "Harmonic Analysis on Homogeneous Spaces", p.177, Prop.7.6.4 for the general (connected) semisimple group case.